# rename a url by replacing "-" to "/"

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have have .htaccess file as follows to show a url ..some.com/designit/portfolio-website-nature?page=2 inplace of ..some.com/designit//portfolio.php?cat=website&subcat=nature?page=2 bt i want to show it as ..some.com/designit/portfolio/website/nature/page2

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.\ ]+)$ $1.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^portfolio-([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)$ portfolio.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^portfolio-([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9.\-\ ]+)$ portfolio.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^portfolio-([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9.\ ]+)-([0-9]+)$ portfolio.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^portfolio-([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)-([0-9]+)$ portfolio.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [QSA]
#RewriteRule ^portfolio-([0-9]+)$ portfolio.php?page=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^projects-([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)$ portfolio_details.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

My main problem is to replace "-" with "/".Please help me.

---

I use WAMPSERVER apache version 2.2.17,OS-WINDOWS,I have .htaccess file in the designit folder.code i have already written.when i running your code and click on a category name the page is oppening with out its slyte,js,images.but the page is working and the url is"http://localhost/designitt/portfolio/categoryname".now again I click on the same link or on another category and the url appears as "http://localhost/designitt/portfolio/portfolio/categoryname" again I click the same link it becomes "http://localhost/designitt/portfolio/portfolio/portfolio/categoryname".I think u got my problem.Please help me when u get time.

Answer (score 0):

The principle is basically:

- if the URL is like "portfolio/aa/bb/cc" then you need to add this params: "`cat=aa`", "`subcat=bb`", "`page=cc`"
- if the URL is like "portfolio/aa/bb" then you need to add this params: "`cat=aa`", "`subcat=bb`"
- if the URL is like "portfolio/aa" then you need to add this params: "`cat=aa`"

This could work like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.\ ]+)$ $1.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)/([0-9]+) /portfolio.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2&page=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+) /portfolio.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+) /portfolio.php?cat=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^projects/([a-zA-Z0-9_.\ ]+)$ /portfolio_details.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Tell me if this works.

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response.I have tried this code. The page is showing but it does not get css,js,images anything.in firebug css,js,images are showing the path "http://localhost/designit/portfolio/images/logo.png" where the right path is "http://localhost/designit/images/logo.png".so what to do?Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: I'd like to but (1) I'm not paid so I help you (like everyone here) on my free time and I haven't got a lot of free time right now (2) you have to give a lot more informations of your configuration : is these vhosts? direct server configuration? htaccess file? which OS: Apple, Linux or M---?

Comment: I use WAMPSERVER apache version 2.2.17,OS-WINDOWS,I have .htaccess file in the designit folder.code i have already written.when i running your code and click on a category name the page is oppening with out its slyte,js,images.but the page is working and the url is"http://localhost/designitt/portfolio/categoryname".now again I click on the same link or on another category and the url appears as "http://localhost/designitt/portfolio/portfolio/categoryname" again I click the same link it becomes "http://localhost/designitt/portfolio/portfolio/portfolio/categoryname".

Comment: Okkkkkkk! Got it: just add the / at the end of the rewriterule. I've edited my answer. Tell me if it works.

Comment: no it is not working it is showing error "page not found" when i click on any category name.I am giving you the code on my navigation page.Here it is:<a href="<?php echo "portfolio-".$data['name']; ?>"...when i wrote your code i also replaced this code with <a href="<?php echo "portfolio/".$data['name']; ?>"..

Comment: I've added an advice, please use it and take a look at the log and try to guess what's going on...